# How check if previous element having active class on click event

Tags: javascript

Considering the below case - I try to check on click event of `<button>` if there was any active class present on its parent `<li>` item.
e.g If the user clicks on button 5, will search and check if the previous `<li>` has an active class or not, in that case, it will return TRUE. Same if the user clicks on button 2, will search on the all previous `<li>` and if not having 'active' class then it will return FALSE.

```
<ul class="list-item">
    <li><button>1</button></li>
    <li><button>2</button></li>
    <li class="active"><button>3</button></li>
    <li><button>4</button></li>
    <li><button>5</button></li>
    <li><button>6</button></li>
    <li><button>7</button></li>
</ul>

const listItem = document.querySelector('.list-item');
if(listItem){
    const alldots = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    alldots.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            // How to check here
            // If there was 'active' class on previous 'li' items on 'click'?
            // 
            
        }, false);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the parent `<li>`.
2. Check if it has the class `active`.
3. Go to its previous sibling and repeat 2.
4. Repeat until either you find something that has the class `active` or there are no more siblings to check.

```js
const listItem = document.querySelector('.list-item');
if(listItem){
    const alldots = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    alldots.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            let anyActive = false;
            let current = event.target.parentElement;
            
            while (current !== null && !anyActive) {
              anyActive = anyActive || current.matches(".active");
              current = current.previousElementSibling;
            }
            
            console.log(anyActive);
            
        }, false);
    });
}
```

```css
.active button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
    <li><button>1</button></li>
    <li><button>2</button></li>
    <li class="active"><button>3</button></li>
    <li><button>4</button></li>
    <li><button>5</button></li>
    <li><button>6</button></li>
    <li><button>7</button></li>
</ul>
```

This will log `true` if the button <kbd>3</kbd> is clicked. If that's undesirable and you want the check to be for only preceding siblings without the current parent, then simply start from the previous sibling `let current = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling;`:

```js
const listItem = document.querySelector('.list-item');
if(listItem){
    const alldots = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    alldots.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            let anyActive = false;
            let current = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
            // start from the previous sibling       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            
            while (current !== null && !anyActive) {
              anyActive = anyActive || current.matches(".active");
              current = current.previousElementSibling;
            }
            
            console.log(anyActive);
            
        }, false);
    });
}
```

```css
.active button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
    <li><button>1</button></li>
    <li><button>2</button></li>
    <li class="active"><button>3</button></li>
    <li><button>4</button></li>
    <li><button>5</button></li>
    <li><button>6</button></li>
    <li><button>7</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have an another JS question, It would be helpfull if you could take a look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737245/javascript-add-line-break-after-specefic-character-count-with-maximum-line-lim

Answer (score 0):

you may be looking for is [ParentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) or [ParentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement).
They are mostly the same except if parentNode is a document and not an element, then parentElement is null.

```js
document.body.parentNode; // the <html> element
document.body.parentElement; // the <html> element

document.documentElement.parentNode; // the document node
document.documentElement.parentElement; // null

(document.documentElement.parentNode === document);  // true
(document.documentElement.parentElement === document);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to which i unsderstood this code will help you :)

```js
const listItemBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item button');
    listItemBtn.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            // If there was 'active' class on previous 'li' items on 'click'?
            const previusSibling = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
            if (previusSibling && previusSibling .classList.contains('active')) {
                alert('has an active class')
            } else {
                alert('doesnt have an active class')
            }

        });
    });
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
        <li><button>1</button></li>
        <li><button>2</button></li>
        <li class="active"><button>3</button></li>
        <li><button>4</button></li>
        <li><button>5</button></li>
        <li><button>6</button></li>
        <li><button>7</button></li>
    </ul>
```

Now if you click on button number 4 it returns alert(has an active class)